# Display unsecure content in IE9

Tags: security, internet-explorer

I have a large webproject that in IE9 doesnt display some of the pages elements since the browser deems them "unsecure" in some way. We can ask our users to enable "display mixed content" in IE9 but would of course prefer to solve this on the server side.

Ive used firebug to track the webtraffic and cant see any http:// requests beeing made via the net-tab. I thought this was what caused the error. Is there any other possible way to troubleshoot this.. I just dont know what elements or settings could cause this problem (since all our traffic seems to go through https it has to be something else IE is reacting to?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weve done some more searching and the error occured because document.write isnt allowed to print at all to our page in IE9. Its perceived as insecure.